# Edit User Profile Page and Profile Picture. Using Real-Time Database flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-streambuilder

I am trying to pull user data from my UserProfileBrowse Data model and display it on my user profile edit page. Including the image. I also want to update the data into my real-time Database.
[image: User Profile Edit Page Display]

[image: RealTime Database in firestore]

THIS IS MY DATA MODEL

```
class UserProfileBrowse {
  String userId;
  int age;
  String name;
  String email;
  String imageUrl;

  UserProfileBrowse(
    this.userId,
    this.age,
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.imageUrl,
  );

  Map<dynamic, dynamic> toJson() => <dynamic, dynamic>{
        'userId': userId,
        'age': age,
        'name': name,
        'email': email,
        'imageUrl' : imageUrl,
      };
}
```

THIS IS MY USER PROFILE EDIT PAGE

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../services/auth.dart';
import 'home.dart';
import 'settings.dart';
import 'package:shadow_app_project/data_models/user_profile_browse.dart';
import 'package:shadow_app_project/image_selection/user_edit_image.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class SettingsUI extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingsUI({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Setting UI",
      home: EditProfilePage(),
    );
  }
}

class EditProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditProfilePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditProfilePageState createState() => _EditProfilePageState();
}

class _EditProfilePageState extends State<EditProfilePage> {

  String currentUser = (Auth().auth.currentUser as User).email.toString();
  TextEditingController displayNameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController ageController = TextEditingController();
  bool isLoading = false;
  User? user;
  UserProfileBrowse? userModel;
  String? imageUrl;
  final refDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  bool showPassword = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        elevation: 1,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => const SettingsPage()));
          },
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.settings,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => const SettingsPage()));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 25, right: 16),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
          },
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              const Text(
                "Edit Profile",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 130,
                height: 130,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                        width: 4,
                        color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          spreadRadius: 2,
                          blurRadius: 10,
                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                          offset: const Offset(0, 10))
                    ],
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: const DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        image: NetworkImage(
                          "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3307758/pexels-photo-3307758.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=250",
                        ))),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 35,
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Name",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.teal)),
                  hintText: 'Input Name',
                ),
                controller: displayNameController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Age",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.teal)),
                  hintText: 'Input Age',
                ),
                controller: ageController,
                //
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text("Email: ", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 35,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: const Text("CANCEL",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            letterSpacing: 2.2,
                            color: Colors.black)),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref()
                          .child('useProfileBrowse')
                          .child(user!.uid)
                          .update({
                        'name': displayNameController.text //yes I know.
                      });
                      FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref()
                          .child('useProfileBrowse')
                          .child(user!.uid)
                          .update({
                        'age': ageController.text //yes I know.
                      });
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      "SAVE",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          letterSpacing: 2.2,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am thinking to use a StreamBuilder in my body: with stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('userProfileBrowse').child(user!.uid).onValue,

Any idea how can I display User profile Imageurl, name, and age from my real-time Database
And also edit the information using stream builder or any other method

I have just coded the UI for my profile edit page. I just want someone to help me retrieve data from my data model class and display it on my user edit page. A single line to display just a name from my data model will help a lot to understand how retrieving data works. I have already saved data(imageUrl, name, age) into my data models during the signup process. Just want to display it

Comment: This is a really broad topic, which makes it hard to answer concisely. Is there anything specific in the code that you shared  that is not working the way you expect it to?

Comment: Nope. I have just coded the UI for my profile edit page. I just want someone to help me retrieve data from my data model class and display it on my user edit page. A single line to display just a name from my data model will help a lot to understand how retrieving data works. I have already saved data(imageUrl, name, age) into my data models during the signup process. Just want to display it

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to [Read Data With FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/read-and-write#read-data) which is pretty well covered in the documentation. If that's not what you're asking, can you clarify the question and include the code you've attempted to access your Firebase data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

full example with StreamProvider :

```
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Person {
  Person({required this.name, required this.initialAge});

  final String name;
  final int initialAge;

  Stream<String> get age async* {
    var i = initialAge;
    while (i < 85) {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
        i++;
      });
      yield i.toString();
    }
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(
    StreamProvider<String>(
      create: (_) => Person(name: 'Yohan', initialAge: 25).age,
      initialData: 25.toString(),
      catchError: (_, error) => error.toString(),
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Future Provider"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Center(
          child: Consumer<String>(
            builder: (context, String age, child) {
              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text("Watch Yohan Age..."),
                  const Text("name: Yohan"),
                  Text("age: $age"),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already started to use the Provider as a state management, so I'd recommend using StreamProvider like this:

```
StreamProvider<String>(
  create: (_) => Profile(name: 'Yohan', initialImageURL: ''),
  initialData: ''.toString(),
  catchError: (_, error) => error.toString(),
  child: child(),
  builder: (context) {
        // Pretend this is loading data and reporting the percent loaded.
        
      },
),
)
```

or you can just notify the UI every time you have got a change from the firebase using ChangeNotifier,

for examples, visit [Docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)